# Online English version of the Karveer Mahatmyam

Tags: devi, resource

Namaste.

Can anyone tell me where can I read the English version of the Karveer Mahatmyam, please?
I can only find a few sources, but they are only in the Marathi language.

Grateful if anyone could help

Comment: The Karveer Mahatmya isn't translated into English yet. It is available only in Marathi.